# TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'?

Tags: python, opencv

Whenever im tying to dilate an image using cv2.dilate i get TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src' error for the image I'm giving as input.

```
frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
cv2.imshow("frameDelta",frameDelta)
thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations = 2)
```

I have already tried cv2.UMat(thresh) and when i use that I get TypeError: Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cv2.threshold does yield two return values. The way you assign it, "thresh" will be a tuple with first entry of type integer and second entry the thresholded image.
Use

```
frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
cv2.imshow("frameDelta",frameDelta)
thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations = 2)
```

instead.